# How to avoid using binding in react using es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using window.onerror to log javascript errors to a file like in code below,

```
class ErrorComponent extends react.purecomponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handle_error = this.handle_error.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.onerror = this.handle_error;
    }

    handle_error = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        const payload = {
            'message': message,
            'source': source,
        };
        return false;
    }

    render = () => {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So from above code it is seen i have used bind. if i dont bind handle_error and call like below in componentdidmount

```
componentDidMount () {
    window.onerror = this.handle_error();
}
```

And when i log the the message and source values in handle_error i get them as undefined.

How can i solve it...I dont want to use bind and how can i fix this without binding handle_error method. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use a fat arrow function

The fat arrow function should also pass the `this` context to the `handle_error` function.

```
class ErrorComponent extends react.purecomponent {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => this.handle_error(message, source, lineno, colno, error);
    }

    handle_error = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        const payload = {
            'message': message,
            'source': source,
        };
        return false;
    }

    render = () => {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i had to call it like this window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => this.handle_error(message, source, lineno, colno, error); and it works.

Comment: Ah yes of course. you always need to pass the args that you setup

Answer (score 0):

The 'problem' or inconvenience you are facing is one of the very reasons **arrow function expression** (aka 'fat arrow function') was implemented.

[You can read more about them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Your example code using arrow function expression is below. Please note passing arguments `onerror`.

```js
class ErrorComponent extends react.purecomponent {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => this.handle_error(message, source, lineno, colno, error);
  }

  handle_error = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
    const payload = {
      'message': message,
      'source': source,
    };
    return false;
  }

  render = () => {
    return null;
  }
}
```